# Scikit-learn Scaled Data - Means Not Zero

Tags: python, scikit-learn, scales

I tried to scale the data by referring to the link as follow:
http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/preprocessing.html

However, when I checked the data distribution, the mean returned is NOT ZERO.

Mean: [ -2.81496710e-17  -4.18191513e-16  ... -6.43850535e-15]
Standard Deviation: [ 1.  1.  ... 1.]

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 3):

Those means are very close to 0, it is probably just a numerical precision problem of floating point numbers.

See also this comment in the [source code](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a95203b/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L146):

```
# Verify that mean_1 is 'close to zero'. If X contains very
# large values, mean_1 can also be very large, due to a lack of
# precision of mean_. In this case, a pre-scaling of the
# concerned feature is efficient, for instance by its mean or
# maximum.
```